# PHP script keeps loading until manual refresh from different machine

Tags: php, apache

I am running a PHP web application on a local network (APACHE server) that allows clients to write notes that are stored on the database.

Whenever 3 or more client machines connect to the server, two clients machines will end up waiting for their page to load indefinitely until client 3 performs an action on the application (i.e AJAX drop down menus, confirm button, open another page or refresh the page). The higher the number of clients, the more who wait for that one machine to make an action on the server.

At times (though rarely), all clients wait indefinitely and I have to reset the APACHE server.

When there are 2 clients connected, all is smooth (although I think its because it slims the chance of the waiting issue to almost never). I have tested the server settings and all seems well (just some tweaks from the default settings)

I believe this is related to my code but cannot track the issue.

Upon my research for a solution I have come across these possible solutions but want to ask around if anyone has experienced this issue and their solution:

Multi threading

Output Buffering

Disable Antivirus

Comment: Show some code, create an MVCE. In most cases, that already solves your problem, but in any case it will help others solve your problem. As it stands, this question can not be reasonably answered.

Comment: It is the 'comma on the third line' issue again.

Comment: @RST I am not familiar with the comma on third line issue. Kindly expand

Comment: The point is, you don't supply any relevant information, like code.